# android soft keyboard steal the height

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, expand

I have write a util to expand view, code like this

```
public static void expand(final View v) {
    int initialHeight = v.getHeight();
    int targetHeight = ((View)v.getParent()).getHeight();
    expand(v, initialHeight, targetHeight);
}
```

It works most of the time, but ...

**Problem**

when I want to expand view in `edittext.onClickListener()`, it sucks. Because when click the edittext , the keyboard will pop up, and the `v.getParent().getHeight()` include the keyboard height.

**WANT**

to make `expand(view)` fit the `edittext.onClickListener()`, fill the blank layout(exclude keyboard) with the view.

**Try**

try to use `expand(v, v.getHeight(), ((View)v.getParent()).getHeight() - keyboardHeight);`, but fail to get keyboard height

try to use measuredHeight

```
view.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

but why view.getMeasuredHeight() return 36 pixel, it is a wrong height

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: what do u want exactly, keyboard height?

Comment: @MohitSuthar I want my view expand from top of the screen to top of the keyboard, but it expand to the whole screen, when the keyboard is show, some of it behind the keyboard

Comment: Just add this in Manifest file activity tag: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"